# Rg plugin PopUp Page Close button Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, button, xamarin.forms, popup

I want to add a close button to my popup pages but I want it top right corner like this image:
[image]

That's my popup page :
[image]

How can I shape my pop up like first image ?

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Margin="20"  HeightRequest="400"   VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="Center">

        <cardView:CardView
                            xct:CornerRadiusEffect.CornerRadius="16"
                            BackgroundColor="White"
                            CardViewHasShadow="True"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="Center" 
                            >
            <cardView:CardView.CardViewContent>
                
                <StackLayout Padding="10" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="300"  >

                    <ImageButton Source="@drawable/x.png" Command="{Binding CloseButtonCommand}"  BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="End" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30"/>
                    <Picker Title="Yazıcı Listesi" TitleColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />

                    <Button Text="Kaydet &amp; Yazdır" TextColor="Black"  BackgroundColor="#4DC6C7" FontSize="Small" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />


                </StackLayout>
            </cardView:CardView.CardViewContent>
        </cardView:CardView>


    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your XAML to below

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Test.Views.PopupView"
             BackgroundColor="#40000000">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout HeightRequest="400"   VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Grid Margin="20">
                <Frame CornerRadius="20" HasShadow="False">
                    <StackLayout Padding="10" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="300"  >
                        <Picker Title="Yazıcı Listesi" TitleColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                        <Button Text="Kaydet &amp; Yazdır" TextColor="Black"  BackgroundColor="#4DC6C7" FontSize="Small" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
                <ImageButton Margin="0,-10, -10,0" Source="x.png" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked" BackgroundColor="Transparent" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="End" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

While navigating to page, use PushModalAsync

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PopupView());
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That's the solution. But I wonder something. I used cardview it shown that x button half, only shown in cardview doesn't shown out of this cardview. I tried frame it works with no problem!